# Inserting an element into an already sorted linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am creating a function that inserts an element into a linked list in the correct order without resorting the list. Here's the code I have:

```
public void insert(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();

    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(e, null);
        count++;
    } else {
        Node current = head;

        for (current = head; current != null ;){
            if(current.item.compareTo(e) > 0){
                Node temp = current;
                current = new Node(e, null);
                current.next = temp;
                break;
            }else{
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I'm not sure whats going wrong but when I print it out, it only prints out the first element. Am I somehow not linking to the head node? I want it so if it looks through the list and once it finds the item larger then it, it takes that spot and the larger item gets bumped to next. The linked list constructors have already been created outside the list.

Comment: In the old days, we have to debug our own codes. You learn a lot from it. stackoverflow might be a disservice to new programmers in that regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert a new element into your list, at no point the `next` reference of the previous element is set:

```
if(current.item.compareTo(e) > 0){
    Node temp = current;
    current = new Node(e, null);
    current.next = temp;
    break;
}else
    \\...
```

As a consequence, `next` of the first list element will always point to `null`, effectively leaving the list empty except for the first element.

---

You also never even try to insert the element if the list is not empty and this condition is `false` for each list element:

```
if(current.item.compareTo(e) > 0){
```

Comment: Assuming the list is empty when the function is called on a number that creates the first element in the list and the .next is null. I guess I'm getting lost on how when I compare head.item to the current item, I'm not referencing the .next of the previous. Since head is = current, wouldn't current.next be the pointer?

Comment: Well, `head == current` until you reassign `current = new Node()`.

Comment: Ahh ok so I played around and got it. I added in Node after = head.next; Node before = head; So I could keep the before reference.